# MIPS multiple recurssions

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am making a quicksort algorithm in MIPS and I am having a little trouble figuring this out. I commented where I am having the problem. So I already have the partition function made, I am basing my code off this:

```
Quicksort(A as array, low as int, high as int){
    if (low < high){
        pivot_location = Partition(A,low,high)
        Quicksort(A,low, pivot_location - 1)
        Quicksort(A, pivot_location + 1, high)
    }
}
```

So for where I assign the pivot location I can jump to my partition routine, but How do I do either of the recursive parts. I cannot just jump to the top of the quicksort routine and start again because that would only do one of the recursions and not the other.

```
#------QUICKSORT START----------
QuickSort: #Quicksort(A as array, low as int, high as int){
#$a0 is base address
#$a1 is low
#$a2 is high
#s1 = leftwall
#s3 = pivot_location


slt $t1,$a2,$a1 #if high > low. aka low < high
bne $t1,1,done #if high < low then we are done


pivot: #stuck here


#-------QUICKSORT END-----------





#------- PARTITION START --------------
Partition: #Partition(A as array, low as int, high as int){
sw $s0,0($a0) #$s0 = A[low], aka. pivot = A[low], $s0 = pivot
add $s1,$zero,$a1 #$s1 = low(leftwall), aka. leftwall = low

addi $s2,$a1,1 #$s2 = low + 1, $s2 = i

ploop: #for i = low + 1 to high{
mul $t5,$s2,4 #$t5 = i*4 because we need to increment base address by 4
add $a0,$a0, $s2 #base address + i, $a0 address = i
lw $t2, 0($a0) #$t2 = A[i]
slt $t1,$t2,$s0 #$t2 = A[i], $s0 = pivot, if(A[i] < pivot)
beq $t1,1,swap1
j swap2

#leftwall = leftwall + 1
#swap(A[i], A[leftwall])
swap1:
addi $s1,$s1,1
la $t0, memAddr #t0 = base address
la $t1, memAddr #t1 = base address
mul $t5,$s2,4 
add $t0, $t0, $t5 #$t0 = A[i]
add $t1, $t1, $s1 #t1 = A[leftwall]
lw $t2,0($t0) #t2 = A[i]
lw $t3,0($t1) #t3 = A[leftwall]
sw $t2,0($t1) 
sw $t3,0($t0) #these 2 lines are the swap


#swap(A[low],A[leftwall])
swap2:
la $t0, memAddr #t0 = base address
la $t1, memAddr #t1 = base address
mul $t5,$s1,4 #t0 = leftwall
add $t0,$s1,$t0 #t0 = base address + leftwall
lw $t2,0($t0) #t2 = A[leftwall]
lw $t3,0($t1) #t1 = A[low]
sw $t2,0($t1)
sw $t3,0($t0) #these 2 lines are the swap

j placeholder #return -- leftwall is saved in register s1
#--------PARTITION END---------
```

Sorry my English is not the best so let me know if I did not explain it well. Thank-you

Comment: Recursion is just a subroutine call, albeit to the same function. As such, you should use `JAL` and take all the precautions that you otherwise need to (save & restore `$ra`, set up arguments). This applies to the `Partition()` too, since that is a plain simple function call.

Comment: oooo I see I was only using regular jump and I was really getting confused on how to make it work. I'll give it a go cheers